# Magento show sidebar in the customer login page

Tags: magento, layout, sidebar

I want to show a sidebar in the left side of *customer account login page*. I have successfully placed the sidebar in the *product page* by calling the navigation bar in `catlog.xml` file.

But doing the same method with the `customer.xml` file is not showing the sidebar.

**Note**
By going through the post [*"Magento: Display Categories in Sidebar"*](http://thinkclay.com/technology/magento-display-categories-in-sidebar) I had changed my sidebar in *product page*. But its not working for *customer login page*.

Comment: and what will the sidebar contain in customer account page?

Comment: it will contain the same navigation just like the product page.

Comment: Please post the code you tried for customer here to have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first tell Magento to use the 2 column template for the Customer Account Login page - as standard it uses the 1 column template file and as such wont have either the left or right structural blocks for your sidebar to go into.

Simple to do - best practice would be to add the layout instruction to an existing *or* create a **local.xml** file in your **app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/** folder.

Using the handle `<customer_account_login>` so as to reference the login page, add the following to local.xml

```
<customer_account_login>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2column-left.phtml</template></action><!-- Tells Magento to use 2 Column Left page template -->
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

This will use the template with a left sidebar.

Then, also within the same `<customer_account_login>` handle call in your block to the left structural block...

```
<customer_account_login>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2column-left.phtml</template></action><!-- Tells Magento to use 2 Column Left page template -->
    </reference>
    <reference name="left"><!-- Tells Magento to place the following content in the left structural block-->
        <!-- Your Block Goes Here -->
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

Done.

If you're not comfortable working in a local.xml file you can just amend the content of the `<customer_account_login>` handle in **customers.xml** to use the above mentioned "root" and "left" - you'll find it calls the page/1column.phtml file under root and of course wont yet have a `<reference name="left">`.